# Basic trigger on MongoDB insert

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying to have a triggering on an insert in my collection (mycollection) on my Mongo database (mydatabase). Here is the javascript code ready to trigger on insert.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var triggers = require("mongo-triggers");

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mydatabase', function(err, db) {
  var myCollection = db.collection('mycollection');
  triggers(myCollection).insert(function(document, next) {
    console.log("Triggered on insert");
    next();
  });
});
```

When I use the mongo CLI to make an insert:

```
> use mydatabase
> db.mycollection.insert({"test": 1})
```

Nothing is triggered (no print on stdout). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trigger you're defining using the [`mongo-triggers`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-triggers) library only works within the context of the node.js program where you define the trigger.

So you'd only get the output if you inserted a document in the *same* program that your code sample is from.

MongoDB doesn't have any built-in support for triggers, so this is only a client-side trigger.